# IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, indexing

I am using python-3.x, and I have searched about the following error but could not find the correct solution. The error occurred in the below code.

I have a random numpy binary array and a random numbers array so the code will delete a binary row based on the value of the other array as you can see from the code.

```
import random
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.nan)


for i in range (100):


    binary= np.random.randint (2, size=(10, 4))
    print("binary:" '\n',binary)


    value = np.random.randint (200, size=(10, 1))
    print("value:" '\n',value)




    for i in range (2):
#       the loseer how have the of the binarys who has the smaslets value 
        loser = np.argmin(value)
#        print ("loser:",loser)
#        print("loser:", loser,(value[loser]))
#        print (binary[loser,])
#        print("Loser=", "Index:", loser,"value:",(value[loser]), "binary:",(binary[loser,]))
        print("Index:", loser)
        print("value:",(value[loser]))
        print("binary:",(binary[loser,]))
        print("Loser=", "Index:", loser,"value:",(value[loser]), "binary:",(binary[loser,]))



        binary = np.delete(binary, (loser), axis=0)
        print("binary:" '\n',binary)
```

the Error is: IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9'

**So in my code, where is the problem and how can solve it**
**Any help would be highly appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are accessing outside the bounds of an array.

In your inner loop, you have a line `binary = np.delete(binary, (loser), axis=0)`

Let's say that the first time through, the index (`loser`) of the min value is 9 (the last element of a 10 element array). Your `binary` array is of length 10. You delete that entry from the array. The binary array is now of length 9. The index of the smallest value in the `value` array hasn't changed! So, the next time around, when you attempt to access element 9, via `print("binary:",(binary[loser,]))`, you get an error.

As for solving your problem you're using a single index `loser` determined from one array to access elements in arrays of two different sizes. You need to determine how you want to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you please explain more on how solving this problem

Comment: @azeez There are many ways to solve the problem. The solution you pick should be the one that fits your goals.

Comment: sorry but still didn't catch the answer, I tried in many ways but none of them works. all what I need to do the delete the lowest two rows in the binary array...

Comment: @azeez your code doesn't delete the lowest two rows in the binary array. Right now, it finds the lowest row in the value array and deletes that twice from the binary array. I think you need to take time to understand the error in your current code, then review your code to see if it does what you want. I'm not going to just do your work for you.